# Azure App Service - Mobile Apps - Is this supported?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, mobile-application, azure-appservice

Azure App Service - Mobile Apps , is this currently being supported by Microsoft?  When I go to the documentation on how to implement the service I am seeing following message.

-This content has been retired and may not be updated in the future. The product, service, or technology mentioned in this content is no longer supported.

For example,   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-value-prop

Appreciate the response!

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming problems. This isn’t a programming problem.

Comment: You should you azure app service. Now it is dedicated for web and mobile apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version:

1. "Azure Mobile Apps" - the SDK for ASP.NET Framework and associated libraries - is being supported.  I am the current central maintainer, and I am looking at various upgrades.  Operating in the open, so you can see the work at github.com/azure/azure-mobile-apps
2. "Azure App Service - Mobile Apps" - the in-app-service compatible server component based on the Node.js service with "Easy Tables" is retired and no longer available.

You can check out the new docs at https://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps.

Comment: @adriannall  does it support accessing the endpoints via APIM?

Comment: also other than deploying as web api , does it support micro services architecture?

Comment: I've made a blog post about supporting via APIM - see my blog at https://adrianhall.github.io - as to "micro-services architecture", I don't know what you mean.  Perhaps you can post on the discussions at github.com/azure/azure-mobile-apps and we can have a conversation about it.